# Проблемы с перетягиванием программ при подключении 2-х мониторов Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, монитор

Я работаю с 2-мя мониторами и мне регулрно приходится "перетаскивать" программы с одного монитора в другой. Раньше у меня стояла Win 7 и проблем не было, но теперь (в Win 10), когда я беру мышкой за окно и начинаю его тянуть в право, на другой экран, то окно делится поплам и закрепляется у правого края экрана. Аналогичная проблема при перетаскивании в обратную сторону. Как отключить это? И есть ли какие - то горячие клавиши что бы перекинуть активное окно на 2-ой или 1-ый экран?

Т.е. программа закрепляется вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то есть вы перетащить вообще не можете ничего на другой экран?

Comment: Могу, но это крайне некомфортно, нужно аккуратно подвинуть прогамму, так что бы она только краюшком выходила на второй экран, потом ее замаштобировать и доперетащить уже со второго.

Comment: @BlueScreen попробуйте покопаться в settings->multitasking. Например, выключить snap windows.

Answer (score 0):

В режиме многозадачности убрать галочку с приккрепрять окна к границам экрана:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема. Но я понял, что если окно перемещать с одного монитора на другой быстрым движением, то оно перемещается спокойно, а не приклеивается к краю. Просто нужно делать это быстрее. При этом многозадачность (прикрепление окон) можно оставить. она никак не помешает.